# GRUB INSTALL ERROR during installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: bootloader, 14.04

Few days back i had tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my Windows 8.1 Laptop(factory installed).The installation ended but when the system restarted then the boot menu just showed the Grub Boot menu.It didn't load the Windows Boot Loader.I think it was due to wrong Boot Loader option selected but then i tried to re install Ubuntu and this time it showed:

Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed.
This is a fatal error.

Isnt there a way by which i can install it again from clean without affecting my windows boot loader settings???